# Get absolute position relative to screen of SKEffectNode as it is warped with SKWarpGeometryGrid

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have an SKVideoNode as a child of an SKEffectNode which enables me to skew the video using a 1 row x 1 column  SKWarpGeometryGrid.

As you drag your finger in each quadrant, new corner coordinates are calculated in touchMoved(toPoint fingerPos: CGPoint) and the SKWarpGeometryGrid is then updated in updateGrid()

I also have a blue square centred on the SKView (and therefore on the video’s initial centre). I would like the blue square to follow the videoNode’s centre as the effectNode warps.
I do not want the square added as a child to the effectNode as the square would get warped as well.

I’ve tried various parameter permutations of convert(*:to:) & convert(*:from:)

e.g.

```
blueSquare?.position = self.convert(effectNode!.position, to: self)
```

… but the blue square never moves. Any thoughts?

[image]

code: (replace myFriend.mp4 with a video file to test)

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

let warpGeometryGrid1Col = SKWarpGeometryGrid(columns: 1,rows: 1)

var warpGridPositions: [float2] = [
float2(0.0, 0.0),  float2(1.0, 0.0),
float2(0.0, 1.0),  float2(1.0, 1.0)]
var adjust: Float = 0.005
var previousPosX: CGFloat = 0
var previousPosY: CGFloat = 0
var topLeftX:Float = 0.0
var topLeftY:Float = 1.0
var topRightX:Float = 1.0
var topRightY:Float = 1.0
var bottomLeftX:Float = 0.0
var bottomLeftY:Float = 0.0
var bottomRightX:Float = 1.0
var bottomRightY:Float = 0.0

var blueSquare:SKSpriteNode?
var effectNode: SKEffectNode?

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

// **** add a video file to the project
  let videoNode = SKVideoNode.init(fileNamed: "myFriend.mp4")
videoNode.size.width = self.frame.size.height/3*1.5
videoNode.size.height = self.frame.size.width/3*1.5
videoNode.play()

effectNode = SKEffectNode()
effectNode!.addChild(videoNode)
self.addChild(effectNode!)

blueSquare = SKSpriteNode.init(color: .blue, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
self.addChild(blueSquare!)
}

func updateGrid(){
warpGridPositions = [float2(bottomLeftX, bottomLeftY), float2(bottomRightX, bottomRightY),
                     float2(topLeftX, topLeftY), float2(topRightX, topRightY)]
effectNode!.warpGeometry = warpGeometryGrid1Col.replacingByDestinationPositions(positions: warpGridPositions)

//*********************************
//*********************************
// TRY TO ADJUST POSITION OF blueSquare AS EFFECT 
// NODE IS WARPED KEEPING IT CENTERED ON THE 
// EFFECT NODE'S CHILD VIDEO
blueSquare?.position = self.convert(effectNode!.position, to: self)
//*********************************
//*********************************
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
for t in touches { self.touchMoved(toPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
}

func touchMoved(toPoint fingerPos : CGPoint) {
if fingerPos.y < 0{
  if fingerPos.x > 0{// bottom right
    if fingerPos.x > previousPosX {
      bottomRightX += adjust
    }
    if fingerPos.x < previousPosX {
      bottomRightX -= adjust
    }
    if fingerPos.y > previousPosY {
      bottomRightY += adjust
    }
    if fingerPos.y < previousPosY {
      bottomRightY -= adjust
    }
  }
  else{ // bottom left
    if fingerPos.x > previousPosX {
      bottomLeftX += adjust
    }
    if fingerPos.x < previousPosX {
      bottomLeftX -= adjust
    }
    if fingerPos.y > previousPosY {
      bottomLeftY += adjust
    }
    if fingerPos.y < previousPosY {
      bottomLeftY -= adjust
    }
  }
} else{
  // top right
  if fingerPos.x > 0{
    if fingerPos.x > previousPosX {
      topRightX += adjust
    }
    if fingerPos.x < previousPosX {
      topRightX -= adjust
    }
    if fingerPos.y > previousPosY {
      topRightY += adjust
    }
    if fingerPos.y < previousPosY {
      topRightY -= adjust
    }
  }
  else{ // top left
    if fingerPos.x > previousPosX {
      topLeftX += adjust
    }
    if fingerPos.x < previousPosX {
      topLeftX -= adjust
    }
    if fingerPos.y > previousPosY {
      topLeftY += adjust
    }
    if fingerPos.y < previousPosY {
      topLeftY -= adjust
    }
  }
}

updateGrid()
previousPosX = fingerPos.x
previousPosY = fingerPos.y
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If effectNode is starting from the center of SKScene, the calculation is direct. The viewFrame could to be cached for accelerate calculation.

```
   var videoFrame : CGRect!
        override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

            // **** add a video file to the project
            let videoNode = SKVideoNode.init(fileNamed: "myFriend.mp4")
            videoNode.size.width = self.frame.size.height/3*1.5
            videoNode.size.height = self.frame.size.width/3*1.5
            videoNode.play()
            videoFrame =  (videoNode.frame)

        effectNode = SKEffectNode()
        effectNode!.addChild(videoNode)

        self.addChild(effectNode!)

        blueSquare = SKSpriteNode.init(color: .blue, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
        self.addChild(blueSquare!)
    }

    func updateGrid(){
        warpGridPositions = [float2(bottomLeftX, bottomLeftY), float2(bottomRightX, bottomRightY),
                             float2(topLeftX, topLeftY), float2(topRightX, topRightY)]
        effectNode!.warpGeometry = warpGeometryGrid1Col.replacingByDestinationPositions(positions: warpGridPositions)
         let finalRatio =  ( warpGridPositions.reduce(float2(),+) / 4.0)
         let   finalWidth = videoFrame.origin.x + CGFloat(finalRatio.x) * videoFrame.size.width
         let   finalHeight = videoFrame.origin.y + CGFloat(finalRatio.y) * videoFrame.size.height
         blueSquare?.position = CGPoint.init(x:finalWidth , y: finalHeight)

    }
```

Hope there is no problem.

Comment: Thanks for your perfect answer. Would it be a major difference if the blue square could actually be placed anywhere on the video and keep its relative position while warping? I've spent all day attempting it but failed. By the way the effectNode does always start from the center of the SKScene.

Comment: I update another result for your request. Hop it works with your cases.

Answer (score 1):

It's for the blue square not in the center. As there is nonlinear twist close to edges, the result is better when blue square is within a center region of video.

```
  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

            // **** add a video file to the project
            let videoNode = SKVideoNode.init(fileNamed: "myFriend.mp4")
            videoNode.size.width = self.frame.size.height/3*1.5
            videoNode.size.height = self.frame.size.width/3*1.5
            videoNode.play()
            videoFrame =  (videoNode.frame)



        effectNode = SKEffectNode()
        effectNode!.addChild(videoNode)


        self.addChild(effectNode!)

        blueSquare = SKSpriteNode.init(color: .blue, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
        self.addChild(blueSquare!)
            blueSquare?.position = CGPoint.init(x: 100, y: 100)


    cachedValue = cacheFrame(relativePosition((blueSquare?.position)!, videoFrame))


    }

    var cachedValue : simd_quatd!
func relativePosition(_ point: CGPoint, _ frame: CGRect) -> CGPoint{
    return CGPoint.init(x: (point.x - frame.origin.x) / frame.size.width , y:
    (point.y - frame.origin.y) / frame.size.height
    )
}

func cacheFrame(_ point : CGPoint)-> simd_quatd {
    let x = Double(point.x)
    let y = Double(point.y)
  return  simd_quatd(vector:  double4([(1-x)*(1-y), x*(1-y), (1-x)*y, x*y]))
}

    func updateGrid(){
        warpGridPositions = [float2(bottomLeftX, bottomLeftY), float2(bottomRightX, bottomRightY),
                             float2(topLeftX, topLeftY), float2(topRightX, topRightY)]
        effectNode!.warpGeometry = warpGeometryGrid1Col.replacingByDestinationPositions(positions: warpGridPositions)
        let finalRatio = CGPoint(x: CGFloat( simd_dot( simd_quatd(vector:
    double4( warpGridPositions.map{Double($0.x)})) ,
                                               cachedValue   )),y:
                    CGFloat(  simd_dot(simd_quatd(vector:
        double4( warpGridPositions.map{Double($0.y)})) , cachedValue))
        )

         let   finalWidth = videoFrame.origin.x + CGFloat(finalRatio.x) * videoFrame.size.width

         let   finalHeight = videoFrame.origin.y + CGFloat(finalRatio.y) * videoFrame.size.height
         blueSquare?.position = CGPoint.init(x:finalWidth , y: finalHeight)

    }
```